# Regex extract element in a list using python

Tags: python, regex, list, element

I have a list containing a set of the history of a file. I need to separate each element in the list into several columns and save it to `CSV` file.

The columns I need are `commit_id, filename, committer, date, time, line_number, code`. 
Suppose, this is my list:

```
my_list = [
     'f5213095324 master/ActiveMasterManager.java              (Michael Stack      2010-08-31 23:51:44 +0000   1) /**',
     'f5213095324 master/ActiveMasterManager.java              (Michael Stack      2010-08-31 23:51:44 +0000   2)  *',
     'f5213095324 master/ActiveMasterManager.java              (Michael Stack      2010-08-31 23:51:44 +0000   3)  * Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one',
     'f5213095324 master/ActiveMasterManager.java              (Michael Stack      2010-08-31 23:51:44 +0000   4)  * or more contributor license agreements.',
     ...
     'b5cf8748198 master/ActiveMasterManager.java              (Michael Stack      2012-09-27 05:40:09 +0000 160)           if (ZKUtil.checkExists(this.watcher, backupZNode) != -1) {'
     ]
```

The desired `csv` output:

```
commit_id   | filename                         | committer     | date       | time     | line_number | code 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
f5213095324 | master/ActiveMasterManager.java  | Michael Stack | 2010-08-31 | 23:51:44 | 1           | /**
f5213095324 | master/ActiveMasterManager.java  | Michael Stack | 2010-08-31 | 23:51:44 | 2           | *
f5213095324 | master/ActiveMasterManager.java  | Michael Stack | 2010-08-31 | 23:51:44 | 3           | * Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
f5213095324 | master/ActiveMasterManager.java  | Michael Stack | 2010-08-31 | 23:51:44 | 4           | * or more contributor license agreements.
........
b5cf8748198 | master/ActiveMasterManager.java  | Michael Stack | 2012-09-27 | 05:40:09 | 160         | if (ZKUtil.checkExists(this.watcher, backupZNode) != -1) {
```

I tried using this code:

```
pattern = re.compile(r'(?P<commit_id>\w+)\s+(?P<filename>[^\s]+)\s+\((?P<committer>.+)\s+(?P<date>\d{4}-\d\d-\d\d)\s+(?P<time>\d\d:\d\d:\d\d).+(?P<line_number>\b\d+\b)\)\s+(?P<code>[^"]*)')

with open('somefile.csv', 'w+', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(['commit_id', 'filename', 'committer', 'date', 'time', 'line_number', 'code'])
    for line in my_list:
        writer.writerow([field.strip() for field in pattern.match(line).groups()])
```

In general, the code works. 
But for `line number = 160`, it's written `-1` in column `line_number` and is written only `{` in column `code`.

Is there something missing in the regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem with your pattern is usage of `.+`. If you replace it with `.*?` you will not only solve the issue with line number but also with catching whitespaces after committer name:

```
pattern = re.compile(r'(?P<commit_id>\w+)\s+(?P<filename>[^\s]+)\s+\((?P<committer>.*?)\s+(?P<date>\d{4}-\d\d-\d\d)\s+(?P<time>\d\d:\d\d:\d\d).*?(?P<line_number>\b\d+\b)\)\s+(?P<code>[^"]*)')
```

https://regex101.com/r/f7zjpA/2

**EDIT:**

You didn't mention that you want to keep indentations and your code didn't look like you actually want it. Whitespaces/indentations before the code are removed not only because of the regex pattern. There are two things:

- in regex pattern you used `\s+` before `code` group, which excludes all the whitespaces/indentations. If you want to keep them, replace `\s+` with `\s` which will catch only first one instead all of them:

  ```
  pattern = re.compile(r'(?P<commit_id>\w+)\s+(?P<filename>[^\s]+)\s+\((?P<committer>.*?)\s+(?P<date>\d{4}-\d\d-\d\d)\s+(?P<time>\d\d:\d\d:\d\d).*?(?P<line_number>\b\d+\b)\)\s(?P<code>[^"]*)')
  ```
- in the for loop you use `field.strip()` which removes all whitespaces which are present at the beginning and the end of the string. Modifying the pattern and exchanging:

  ```
  writer.writerow([field.strip() for field in pattern.match(line).groups()])
  ```

  with:

  ```
  writer.writerow(pattern.match(line).groups())
  ```

  will result in keeping indentations where they belong.

Comment: But, if the value in the column 'code' contains indentation, it doesn't work. The regex doesn't keep the indentation at the beginning of the code.

Comment: Check the edit. Explanation for that was a bit too long for the comment.

Comment: Oh, I understand now. It's because of the loop. Thank you for your solution.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed regex.
This should work:

```
pattern = re.compile(r'(?P<commit_id>\w+)\s+(?P<filename>[^\s]+)\s+\((?P<committer>.+)\s+(?P<date>\d{4}-\d\d-\d\d)\s+(?P<time>\d\d:\d\d:\d\d).+?(?P<line_number>\b\d+\b)\)\s+(?P<code>[^"]*)')
```

I added a question mark to use Lazy matching
".+" => ".+?"

https://regex101.com/r/GQGLvy/1

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly you are looking for but this can be useful.

```
import re

for row in my_list:
    print([x.strip() for x in re.split(r"(?![)])\s+(?![(])", row)])

out:

['f5213095324', 'master/ActiveMasterManager.java', '(Michael', 'Stack', '2010-08-31', '23:51:44', '+0000', '1)', '/**']
['f5213095324', 'master/ActiveMasterManager.java', '(Michael', 'Stack', '2010-08-31', '23:51:44', '+0000', '2)', '*']
...
```

Comment: (?![) is negative lookahead. please read: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html